How to return array of array of strings' intersection?
I have an array of array of strings, and I need to return the intersection of its (value-wise) elements.
let arrayOfArrayOfStrings =
[
    ["J", "C", "A", "E"],
    ["A", "C", "J", "E"],
    ["R", "J", "A", "E"]
]

I expect this output: ["A", "E", "J"]

Set has powerful methods to determine the relation of two sets, so a possible solution is to map the inner arrays to Set and call intersection.
let arrayArrayStrings: [[String]] = [
["a", "b", "e"],
["a", "c", "e"],
["a", "d", "e"]]

let arraySetStrings = arrayArrayStrings.map(Set.init)
var commonElements = arraySetStrings[0]
for i in 1..<arraySetStrings.count {
    commonElements.formIntersection(arraySetStrings[i])
}
print(commonElements.sorted())

Another way to check also the position of the elements is to use the difference(from API of Array
let arrayArrayStrings: [[String]] = [
["a", "b", "e"],
["a", "c", "e"],
["a", "d", "e"]]

var commonElements = arrayArrayStrings[0]
var indicesToRemove = IndexSet()
for i in 1..<arrayArrayStrings.count {
    let diff = commonElements.difference(from: arrayArrayStrings[i])
    diff.removals.forEach { removal in
        if case .remove(offset: let offset, element: let element, associatedWith: let associatedWith) = removal {
            indicesToRemove.insert(offset)
        }
    }
}
commonElements.remove(atOffsets: indicesToRemove)
print(commonElements)


Note, however, that if "same elements" means "same and in the same index position", or if the arrays have repeated elements, this might not get the desired result. Part of the problem here is that the OP has not specified the problem with sufficient precision.

@matt Good point. I added an alternative preserving the position of the elements.

formIntersection takes a Sequence as argument, it does not have to be a Set. So you don't have to convert all subarrays to sets. Whether that is more efficient or not  may depend on the sizes of the arrays.
